# Prime parallel rows for the first 20 numbers

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, primes

Two positive integers can be joined with a straight segment if their sum is a prime and the segment doesn't intersect any other segments. What is the most number of pairs you can join if you can place numbers from 1 to 20 in two parallel rows?

Comment: The full lines must not intersect, or just the line segments between the two numbers?

Comment: Just the line segments. Updated the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 20 09 08 03 10 19 12 05 06 07
>
>  17 14 15 16 13 18 11 02 01 04

This results in

> 28 pairs.

Note that

> no triangle allowed.

---

A proof of optimality:

> Without loss of generality, assume that the two rows are located on integral points on the plane, on the lines $y = 0$ and $y = 1$, respectively. Also assume that the points on each row are consecutive (e.g. from $(0, 0)$ to $(9, 0)$, etc.).
>
>
>  Connect all the pairs. This creates a planar graph. Let $e$ be the number of edges (i.e. line segments), and let $g$ be the number of "holes", i.e. loops created by the line segments. These are called "faces" in the link cited below.
>
>
>  We then have [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler's_formula), which states $20 - e + g = 1$ (note that our definition of $g$ excludes the outer, infinitely large region).
>
>
>  So it suffices to show that $g \leq 9$. But we know that the area of each "hole" is a half integer (e.g. by [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem)), and their sum is $\leq 9$ (the area of the convex hull, which must have area $9$, again by [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem)).
>
>
>  Moreover, since triangles are not allowed, no hole can have area $\frac{1}{2}$ (again by [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem)), and hence every hole has area $\geq 1$.

Comment: Sorry for my terrible counting...

Comment: All good! Can you do better or can you prove that this is the optimal?

Comment: A proof is added.

Comment: I'm actually a bit curious: did you already know the solution before posting the question? This is indeed an interesting puzzle and could be a very good question in math contests.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it was the answer but wasn't sure how to prove it.

Comment: The "e.g. from $(0,0)$ to $(9,0)$" might read as suggesting there must be 10 on each row, but the proof works just as well with any number on each row totalling 20.